# Exception In Initializer Error in Java

Tags: java, r

I'm trying to execute a protocol through R's console and everytime I get this error:

```
Error in .jnew("gr.demokritos.iit.radio.home.orchestration.Controller") :
  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

I tried to google the error and I only understand that there's something wrong with the static block. Although it seems normal to me.

The two static blocks that exist in the mentioned class:

```
static ComputationService service;

static {
    String conf_path = System.getProperty("config.file", "/root/application.conf");
    Config my = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(conf_path));
    Config config = my.withFallback(ConfigFactory.load());
    service = ComputationService$.MODULE$.apply(ActorSystem.apply("benaloh", config));
}
```

The full source files that are referenced:

1. [ttest.r](https://bitbucket.org/dataengineering/rassp/src/cb0a5359c1597c83559f625b5a33a4c829cf8523/RStats/R/ttest.R?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) (jnew at line 55)
2. [controller.java](https://bitbucket.org/dataengineering/rassp/src/cb0a5359c1597c83559f625b5a33a4c829cf8523/stats/src/main/java/gr/demokritos/iit/radio/home/orchestration/Controller.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: Indeed, there is an exception being thrown in the static block, but without the stack trace it won't be easy to find out what's wrong. BTW, there's only one static block, the static initializer: `static { ... }`

Comment: @TNT Sorry for being a newbie, but how can I find the stack trace? The execution occurs inside of R's console.

Comment: Hmm. I have no experience with R, but if you can get the console to display both STDOUT and STDERR, such as redirecting the latter to the former, you'll probably find the stack trace. (I'm making the assumption that what you're seeing is from STDOUT.)